# Cumulative sum by month with missing months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to cumulative sum by month a quantity but in some months there's no quantity and SQL does not show these rows.

I have tried multiple other solutions I found here but none of them worked or at least I couldn't get them working. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         A.FromDate
        ,A.ToDate
        ,A.OperationType
        ,A.[ItemCode]
        ,SUM(A.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemCode],OperationType,YEAR ORDER BY MONTH) [Quantity]

 FROM (
        SELECT 
         CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, T.OrderDate), 0)) AS FromDate
        ,EOMONTH(T.OrderDate) ToDate
        ,DATEPART(MONTH, t.OrderDate) AS [Month]
                ,DATEPART(YEAR, t.OrderDate) AS [Year]
                ,SUM(T.[Quantity]) [Quantity]
        ,OperationType
        ,[ItemCode]
        FROM TEST T

        WHERE [ItemCode] != ''

        GROUP BY T.OrderDate,[ItemCode],OperationType
        
      ) A
```

With these results:

| FromDate | ToDate | OType | ItemCode | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 | Type1 | 1 | 19 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-28 | Type1 | 1 | 96 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | Type1 | 1 | 116 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-30 | Type1 | 1 | 138 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 | Type1 | 1 | 178 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-07-31 | Type1 | 1 | 203 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-08-31 | Type1 | 1 | 228 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-09-30 | Type1 | 1 | 253 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-11-30 | Type1 | 1 | 330 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | Type1 | 1 | 364 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-28 | Type1 | 1 | 18 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 | Type1 | 1 | 42 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 | Type1 | 1 | 53 |

And I was expecting these results:

| FromDate | ToDate | OType | ItemCode | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 | Type1 | 1 | 19 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-28 | Type1 | 1 | 96 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | Type1 | 1 | 116 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-30 | Type1 | 1 | 138 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-05-31 | Type1 | 1 | 138 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 | Type1 | 1 | 178 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-07-31 | Type1 | 1 | 203 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-08-31 | Type1 | 1 | 228 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-09-30 | Type1 | 1 | 253 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-10-31 | Type1 | 1 | 253 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-11-30 | Type1 | 1 | 330 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | Type1 | 1 | 364 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-28 | Type1 | 1 | 18 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 | Type1 | 1 | 42 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 | Type1 | 1 | 53 |

SQL Fiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04a997/1

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Are you providing an input parameter like only this operationtype and/or only this itemcode?

Comment: Typically you would outer-join with a *calendar table* or some artifically generated sequence that fills in the gaps.

Comment: @Rhythm Was a Lurker No, I only showed one itemcode and one operationtype in the example for simplicity.

Comment: @Stu That was my first thought, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: it would help if you showed this query, even if it's not working as desired, so we can point out where the issue is. do you have a calendar table to join to? A good calendar table will have columns for year, month and day for uses like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
WITH m(Earliest,Latest) AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,MIN(EOMONTH(OrderDate,-1))),
    MAX(EOMONTH(OrderDate)) FROM dbo.TEST
), TypeCodes AS 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ItemCode, OperationType
  FROM dbo.TEST
), Months AS
(
  SELECT Month = DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)-1, Earliest)
  FROM m CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',',
    DATEDIFF(MONTH,Earliest,Latest)),',')
), raw AS
(
  SELECT m.Month, i.OperationType, i.ItemCode, 
    Q = COALESCE(SUM(Quantity),0)
  FROM Months AS m
  CROSS JOIN TypeCodes AS i
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TEST AS t
  ON t.OrderDate >= m.Month
  AND t.OrderDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.Month)
  AND i.ItemCode = t.ItemCode
  AND i.OperationType = t.OperationType
  GROUP BY m.Month, i.OperationType, i.ItemCode
)
SELECT FromDate = Month, 
       ToDate = EOMONTH(Month),
       OperationType, 
       ItemCode, 
       Quantity = SUM(Q) OVER (ORDER BY Month)
FROM raw;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04a997/8).

If you can't use `STRING_SPLIT()` because your database is stuck on an older compatibility level, you could put this function in a database that isn't:

```
USE ModernDatabase;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StringSplit(@list nvarchar(max), @delim nchar(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@list, @delim));
```

Then you change:

```
FROM m CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(...
```

To:

```
FROM m CROSS APPLY ModernDatabase.dbo.StringSplit(...
```

Comment: Would it be possible to achieve the same thing without using the string split ? In other words, I need to implement this on a DB which has compatibility level set to 120 (SQL Server 2014) and I can't change it. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @GonçaloFigueiredo Well couldn't you just use a wrapper function in a different database that isn't stuck on an old compat level? How long are you going to keep it on 120 (and why)?

Comment: sorry for the delay but your solution worked perfectly. I can't update, because the server is not mine.

Comment: @GonçaloFigueiredo Sure, but you could have the owner of the server put that function somewhere or, better, update the compat level.